# How do I force a folder sort for my downloaded music on Rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox, music, downloads, sort

When I import music from an external source, it sorts it into the nice and organized folders by artist - album, but when I import music from Downloads, it just references the file in Downloads and doesn't sort it. How can I force Rhythmbox to sort my downloaded music. Ubuntu 10.10, Rhythmbox 0.13.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean you want the files to be placed in a directory hierarchy on import I'm afraid it looks like rhythmbox doesn't currently support this feature. There is a bug open in the GNOME bugzilla:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=636980

If you are not tied to rhythmbox, banshee (which will be the default media player in future Ubuntu versions) does support this operation.

Comment: What menu option lets you do this in banshee?

Comment: In Edit->Preferences, check "Copy files to media folders when importing". It will then happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also like this feature built in, but for the time being there's a plugin for Rhythmbox called 'File Organizer': [How do I force Rhythmbox to automatically organise my music files into folders?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112668/how-do-i-force-rhythmbox-to-automatically-organise-my-music-files-into-folders)