# How do I force Rhythmbox to automatically organise my music files into folders?

Tags: gnome, music, rhythmbox, directory

How do I force Rhythmbox to automatically organise my music files into folders (corresponding to the artist and album) in Ubuntu 12.04 beta-1.  Is this functionality currently missing from the new version?

Answer (score 7):

This feature is not built into Rhythmbox by default and not among the default set of plug-ins. However, there is a third party plugin for rhythmbox that provides this functionality.

To get it working, you have to install two new packages, [download][1] the plugin and install it manually.

1. Install `python-eyed3` and `gir1.2-notify-0.7` from the Ubuntu Software Centre.
2. Download the plugin called "File Organizer" from the [Rhythmbox Third Party Plugins page](https://live.gnome.org/RhythmboxPlugins/ThirdParty#File_Organizer) and extract the contents of the `tar.gz` file.
3. Give execution privileges to the file called `INSTALL` by following [these](https://askubuntu.com/a/138911/2405) instructions, then run it by double-clicking on it.
4. Open Rhythmbox and activate the plugin by choosing `Edit -> Plugins`, and checking the box next to the "File Organiser" entry.

You can now right-click on a track in Rhythmbox (or select multiple tracks) and click "Organize selection" to rename and arrange the track(s) into folders.

You can change the naming scheme and folder hierarchy under the Music tab in the normal Rhythmbox preferences dialogue.

Answer (score 6):

This plugin is now available through my PPA:

- https://launchpad.net/~fossfreedom/+archive/rhythmbox-plugins

The package is called `rhythmbox-plugin-fileorganizer`

PPA installation instructions are in the linked question.

Activate the plugin through the global menu option *Edit - plugins*

[image]

If you are feeling nervous - check the *Preview Mode Enabled* box and no changes will be made to rhythmbox - instead, a report of potential changes will be presented in your favourite text editor

[image]

Right click the tracks you wish to organise as shown and click the *Organize selection* menu option.

---

Linked Question:

- [How do I install third-party rhythmbox plugins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147942/how-do-i-install-third-party-rhythmbox-plugins)

Comment: Work great. Is source code available?

Comment: https://github.com/lachlan-00/rb-fileorganizer