# How to execute a script just by double clicking like .EXE files in Windows?

Tags: launcher, scripts, executable

How can I make a bash script executable by double clicking just like `.exe` files in Windows? I tried [creating a launcher and assigning the script to it](https://askubuntu.com/q/34597/24694), but there are two consequences:

1. the terminal twinkles, disappears, and nothing is done.
2. you must specify to run in terminal in order to work.

I have a script that installs tomcat on an offline PC, including all dependencies of tomcat in the script. I need to make the script work on double clicking like windows since most who use the script will not be familiar with Ubuntu.

*Forget the above explanation. I want to make a script that can be run by double-clicking on it, without using the terminal. Anybody knows how?*

Comment: I think you may just be writing your desktop file poorly. Can you post (**verbatim**) the .desktop launcher that you wrote?

Comment: Also, have you seen this? http://askubuntu.com/q/34597/24694

Comment: Its just a launcher where you assign name and command to do its not that big idea

Comment: Also note, that scripts in linux are not called _bash_ but _shell_ afaik.

Comment: muru tipped me off to this, worked for me: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus

Comment: FYI for future visitors: Nautilus, the default file manager on Ubuntu, apparently will be removing the ability to run executables in newer releases in 2019 due to vulnerabilities. [Article on the topic](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/05/nautilus-remove-ability-launch-binaries-apps) and [code commit on GitLab with discussion](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/commit/3a22ed5b8e3bbc1c59ff3069ee79755168754916)

Answer (score 164):

I tested this and it worked fine. Ensure your script begins with the correct [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), e.g. [`#!/usr/bin/env bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383546/4970442) .

Then follow these steps:

- Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to run a command.
- Type `dconf-editor` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- In dconfg-editor go to: `org ➤ gnome ➤ nautilus ➤ preferences`
- Click on `executable-text-activation` and from drop down menu select:

  **launch**: to launch scripts as programs.
  OR
  **ask**: to ask what to do via a dialog.

  [image: screenshot]
- Close dconf-editor. Thats it!

Alternative way, using terminal: Run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences executable-text-activation 'launch'
```

**Note**: The file should be executable. You may also need to change permission of file. Right click and set "Allow executing file as program"

[image: screenshot]

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/286631/349837).

Comment: This worked great. Just a note, the "drop down menu" is reached by clicking on the value listed to the right of `executable-text-activation` (default value is `display`).

Comment: for those who cannot call the app, you need to install it first with `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`

Comment: This works everywhere except on the Desktop. How can I make it work on the Desktop as well? I'm using Xubuntu 14.10.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in LXDE (for Lubuntu)?

Comment: This works great under slax unix to -- see http://slax.org for the really great Unix system you can boot off of a thumb drive.

Comment: Nice answer!! This answer should be mark as correct right? Haha..

Comment: Works great on RHEL 7.2 as well... Saved me some digging..

Comment: Is there a way to make this work in XFce?

Comment: Major issue: *.cpp files also seem to attempt to execute, however that of course does nothing. It's quite a pain.

Comment: Alt+F2 is supposed to launch the terminal right? Wasted a few minutes there, trying to launch dconf-editor in tty of Ctrl+Alt+F2, as Alt+F2 did nothing in my system. Just had to launch the terminal, launch dconf-editor there. Worked.

Answer (score 100):

On Nautilus (AKA Files)

1. Go to Files (*Edit* on Unity (17.04 or below)) > Preferences > Behavior tab

   [image: screenshot]
2. Change the settings for executable text file.

   [image: screenshot]

Comment: Now 'Files -> Preferences'. (17.04)

Comment: Sweet! The way to go imho.

Comment: How to see output ?

Answer (score 19):

I think creating a **.desktop* file is missing here:

```
$ cat shortcut-for-my-script.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=Click-Script
Icon=utilities-terminal
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "bash -c './script.sh;$SHELL'"
Categories=Application;
```

If you create more than one **.desktop* file for one script you are able to create multiple *configurations* by passing different parameters, which is a very comfortable and user-friendly way.

Comment: This the best answer for Ubuntu.  Note that you may not (or probably do not?) need to specify `Terminal=True` and `Exec=gnome-terminal` unless you are literally creating a shortcut for a script that you want to see the output of within a terminal window... Also note that you can point `Icon` to whatever custom png you might want...

Comment: get this as untrusted tho

Comment: I was launching a script that launches other applications, and them crashed after a couple of seconds, being hit by SIGHUP. Using `bash -c "./script.sh; $SHELL"` like stated here solved the problem. Great!

Answer (score 10):

In Ubuntu and all Unix based OSes, afaik, nothing is set as executable by default. There are two ways of doing this.

1. Right click on the script or file you want to execute. Go to Properties then to the Permissions Tab. Click the check box that says Execute.
2. Open a Terminal [`cd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/cd.1posix.html) into the directory where the file is found. Type `chmod ugo+x filename`. This will set the file to execute.

Now your users can double click to their hearts content.

Comment: It still will ask you what to do with run in terminal or display or run ... So its not what i need

Comment: Only this answer worked on Gnome Ubuntu 17.04 for making desktop file executeable

Comment: This is for executing file on terminal, not by double clicking it.

Comment: This method does not allow you to be able to launch by double clicking.

Answer (score 10):

## For Ubuntu 20.04:

1. Open *Files* (*Nautilus* is called *Files* now), click on the hamburger menu and select **Preferences**.

[image]

2. Go to the **Behaviour** tab and select what's suitable from the **Executable Text Files** section

[image]

Answer (score 8):

If you're using XFce then you can make script executed in Thunar by executing this command:

```
xfconf-query --channel thunar --property /misc-exec-shell-scripts-by-default \
             --create --type bool --set true
```

or by using gui `xfce4-settings-editor` and creating the same properties.

Run `xfce4-settings-editor`, then enter:

- `/misc-exec-shell-scripts-by-default`
- Boolean
- TRUE

[image: picture of xfce4-settings-editor]

Comment: [Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1170255/925128) on how to achieve the purpose with custom actions in Thunar (without re-enabling that "risky" feature).

Comment: Also [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/876581/925128) on how to use Zenity and get a question "Edit or Run?"

Answer (score 2):

You have to check 3 points :

- Nautilus / Nemo configuration : https://askubuntu.com/a/286651/301025
- The script file must be *executable*: https://askubuntu.com/a/275714/301025
- The file system must allow *execution* :

  1. Type `mount` in a console
  2. Check if your file system has the `noexec` flag
  3. Remove the `noexec` flag by editing `/etc/fstab` and remount the modified system (eg. a reboot works)

Answer (score 1):

When you create a launch in Desktop to a SHEL script or Whatever, in command line, don't forget to signal the script, to be executed in background.

The script will die when he finished is job.

Comment: i did that but what prob is the terminal just twinkles and nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

Based on `umask` defualt value, you haven't execute permissions for files by default and must change mod to gain execute permissions, something like this:

```
chmod u+x filename
```

Comment: Broth Ali sure i did it its obvious to do that

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to [the answer about Thunar](https://askubuntu.com/a/871986/925128): that answer would re-enable a previous feature of Thunar to execute scripts on double click. But that feature was considered a security risk.

To avoid that, maybe the most elegant solution is to get a pop-up window with a question like "What do you want to with that file: Run or edit?" (similar to what you have in other file managers like PCManFM and Nemo) when clicking that file - by using Zenity: [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/876581/925128).

---

An alternative would be **custom actions**, perhaps the best feature Thunar has.

The command that I use for running an executable text file is `sh -c %f`, for a custom action called "Run/Execute script".

[image]

The appearance conditions are simply "text":

[image]

A similar command can be used for running in terminal a such script ("Run in terminal"), while keeping the Xfce4 terminal open:

```
xfce4-terminal -H -x %f
```

[image]

Optionally, and maybe preferably, in order to hide such options for all text files except the executable ones, a way is to restrict appearance use to `.sh` files (or `.py` files if the case, etc), under "Appearance conditions":

[image]

-- before renaming the executable files accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Still in 2023, i found hard to run scipts (sh files) in linux desktop.  In my case, run **lxqt configuaration center** from menu, then **KDE system Setting** (or any other relevant setting), then Applications, then search for ".sh" or **x-shellscript** then in **application order**, add ANY application, then edit the "top one", and change everything in "**application tab**" (in edit) as ***"bash" or "bash -c" or "sh -c"***, whatever works for you. Try it on terminal like `bash script.sh` to see if it works.

Answer (score -1):

Specially for Android Studio You can follow my [original answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/735658/410659):

## To Create Desktop Launcher:

- Click on `Create Desktop Entry..` from **Tools** menu.

[image]

- It will be prompt for password, enter password of your current login.
- Finally it will be display notification in Android Studio screen like:

[image]

- You can see in **Applications => Programming => Android Studio**, and you may see on desktop also after restarting system.

Thank you. :)

Answer (score -1):

OS: Linux Mint (I'm using 18.3)

I struggled for ages with this, trying to find out how you can click (or double-click) an executable item and get it to run, without further questions.  I looked at all the stuff under Nemo Edit --> Preferences. The answer is actually very simple, and set up for you... I don't know whether this applies solely to Mint.

On the desktop, right-click and choose "+ Create a new launcher here". One of the simplest imaginable dialogs then follows, where you have to choose your executable file, and whether you also want to create a new item in the Start menu, i.e. to run using exclusively keyboard.

What this actually creates is a simple executable text file, e.g.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=
Terminal=true
Name=MyScript
Exec=/media/mike/D_drive/My Documents/sysadmin/MyScript.sh
Type=Application
```

There's no requirement for this file to have ".desktop" in its name.

This file can be used elsewhere than on the desktop: move/copy it into another directory and it will also run with a double-click in Nemo (or single click if Nemo is so configured).