# How do I run executable scripts in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, execute-command

When I double-click on a script in Nautilus to run it, the script just opens in my text editor with no option to run it. Using Nautilus, how do I run executable text files and/or scripts?

Comment: The default behavior is a bug. Users should not have to fiddle with settings to make this work. I've filed https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1433774.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute a script just by double clicking like .EXE files in Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/138908/how-to-execute-a-script-just-by-double-clicking-like-exe-files-in-windows)

Comment: @StefanMonov if anything, the dupe should be the other way.

Answer (score 229):

1. Open Nautilus.
2. Open this from the menu bar:

   > **Edit → Preferences**
3. Select the 'Behavior' tab.
4. Select "Ask each time" under "Executable Text Files".
5. Close the window.
6. Right click the file, and select "Properties.
7. Select the "Permissions" tab, and make sure "Allow executing file as program" is selected.
8. Close the window.

Now you can double-click your executable text file in Nautilus to be asked whether to execute or edit your script.

[image]

---

Answer credit: [Nur](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus#comment360166_286631)

Comment: What a weird default to have. And not even a right-click option to just run the file. Very unfriendly to users.

Comment: What about I want it to always run in terminal?

Comment: On step #2, "Open this from the menu bar"... where is the menu bar? I don't see an "Edit" menu anywhere. I see my files in the middle, several local and network locations on the left, and a menu button in the top right which just has buttons such as "new tab" and undo/redo. The top just has the back/forward buttons and the list of folders I'm in.

Comment: @AaronFranke: In ubuntu the menu bar shows when you hover the dark bar on the top of the screen.

Comment: @StefanMonov I'm using Xubuntu, not Ubuntu, and so I don't have a dark bar at the top of the screen.

Comment: I was also able to use this answer for the similar "Files" app, whatever is is called underneath, in my Fedora installation!

Comment: @Pysis The "Files" in Fedora is exactly Nautilus. Try `nautilus` in terminal.

Comment: @AaronFranke Hamburger menu > preferences... then behavior tab, sorry for the 3 year+ delay

Comment: @AaronFranke: that's another oddity in GNOME: placing important menu items in the window title bar, unlike all other desktop environments. The title bar is for open/close/minimize buttons, and users just don't look there for other stuff, like [search](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1878301).

Answer (score 37):

Follow these steps:

- Install `dconf-editor` because it isn't installed by default.
- Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `dconf-editor` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- In `dconfg-editor` goto: `org` ➤ `gnome` ➤ `nautilus` ➤ `preferences`

  [image]
- Click on `executable-text-activation` and from drop down menu select:

  **launch**: to launch scripts as programs.

  OR

  **ask**: to ask what to do via a dialog.
- Close `dconf-editor`. That's it!

Comment: You can also open nautilus, click Files > Preferences, check behaviour tab, and select the option you prefer for Executable Text Files, open with text editor is the default.

Comment: Although this works too, dconfg-editor is the worst possible way of changing application configuration.

Comment: This answer was very helpful for me, even though using the preferences dialog would "normally" be a better answer, as I'm using a tiling window manager and the "Files" menu appears to be completely inaccessible!

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04, the `executable-text-activation` key doesn't exist.

Answer (score 15):

I think this is a nuisance caused by Gnome people who decided to change that default behavior we were accustomed to.

To fix it, you can;

1. install (if you haven't already) and start **dconf Editor**,
2. go to: **org > gnome > nautilus > preferences**, and
3. change the value for **executable-text-activation** back to **ask** (or even **launch**, if you prefer).

If you want the same Nautilus behavior as Root as well you can repeat the steps above, starting **dconf Editor** this time as **Root**.

Answer (score 15):

in a terminal

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences executable-text-activation ask
```

Comment: +1: This works in older versions of Linux, even before the dconf method became available.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, IMHO.

Comment: Is there a way to apply this same configuration for all users?  (Either for all existing users, or for all users created in the future, or both?)

Comment: I believe yes. im not sure how to do it. maybe you can update it in /etc/profile or /etc/bash.bashrc

Answer (score 4):

### Using GUI

1. Depending on which Ubuntu version you have,

   - #### 14.04 or 16.04

     In Nautilus, open this from the menu bar:

     > Edit → Preferences
   - #### 18.04+

     In Nautilus, open this from the menu bar:

     > Files → Preferences
2. Then, in the 'Behavior' tab, select "Run them" (previously "Run executable text files with they are opened").

   Alternatively, select "Ask each time" instead if you would like a dialog ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtShb.png)) asking you whether to edit or execute the file.

   [image: screenshot]

### Using Command line

If you prefer a command:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/executable-text-activation "'launch'"
```

---

**Note**: Both GUI and command line methods work only for Nautilus (the default graphical file manager in Ubuntu).

Originally from another answer posted by me [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/411937/176889).

Comment: @DKBose: The command 'dconf' is in Ubuntu by default. dconf-editor only provides the GUI program to edit dconf.

Comment: You are correct. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2):

For that I guess the best way will be to make **.desktop** launcher, make that launcher executable using

```
chmod +x blah.desktop
```

And after that you will be ready to run it via just clicking, and even more you can add it to launcher. To read more about how to make **.desktop** files look [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/64222/47044). Main part of it is this

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=/path/to/icon/icon.svg
Name=give-name-here
Exec=/path/to/file/executable
```

Comment: Opening the associated script editor instead of launching the script is already a problem for executable `.desktop` files as seen in [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1433774), so this answer doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this for a single file by going into permissions in file properties and selecting "run this file as an executable".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the most upvoted answer in Fedora 20 + GNOME too:

```
Open Nautilus, check Preferences -> Behavior -> Executable Files, put as always ask
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check 3 points :

- Nautilus / Nemo configuration : https://askubuntu.com/a/286651/301025
- The script file must have *executable* permission : https://askubuntu.com/a/275714/301025
- The file system must allow *execution* :

  1. Type "mount" in a console
  2. Check if your file system has *noexec* flag
  3. Remove *noexec* flag in editing /etc/fstab and

Answer (score 0):

right click on the file -> open with -> other application -> view all applications -> run software -> select

from now on shell scripts will be run on double click.

Comment: except they won't. don't even appear in htop, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In **Nautilus 45.0+**, try this steps

1. Create desktop file at ~/.local/share/applications

```
[Desktop Entry]
.....
Exec=bash %f
Name=Script_launcher_1
NoDisplay=true
Terminal=true or false
.....
```

2. Create bash script file and make it executable

```
#!/bin/bash 
# with or without shebang line

# write commands
.....
```

3. In Nautilus, right-click the script file, click "Open with", select the created desktop entry name in the list, and check "Always use for this file type".
4. You can then run the script file by double-clicking it in Nautilus.

---

---

To target specific file extension, for example *.ext1, try this steps also.

1. Create XML file for MIME type definition in

```
~/.local/share/mime/packages/my-custom-mime-types.xml 
or 
/usr/share/mime/packages/my-custom-mime-types.xml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
        <mime-type type="my-custom-mime-types/custom-ext1-mime-type">
                <comment>My Custom EXT1 MIME Type</comment>
                <glob pattern="*.ext1"/>
        </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

2. Update MIME database using one of following command

```
update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

3. Result file is as follows

```
~/.local/share/mime/my-custom-mime-types/custom-ext1-mime-type.xml
or
/usr/share/mime/my-custom-mime-types/custom-ext1-mime-type.xml
```

Additional MIME types can be added to the my-custom-mime-types.xml file, then run the 'update-mime-database' again. For more details, see https://blog.robertelder.org/custom-mime-type-ubuntu/

Answer (score -1):

1. Open Nautilus. (File Browser)
2. 1. In Ubuntu 17.04, now we can cummulative bar so Preferences in available in Files.
   2. Open this from the menu bar:
3. Files → Preferences
4. Select 'Behavior' tab
5. Select "Ask what to do" under "Executable Text Files".

   [image: preferences]
6. Close it.

Comment: duplicate answer