# How to run a script directly when double clicked?

Tags: nautilus

To execute a script, I have to:

1. Write the script
2. Make it executable
3. Double click it, which shows this window:

   [image]
4. Click the "Run" button.

How can I execute the script directly, without showing the dialog?

Comment: please stop editing question so fast

Comment: @adityapatil I just want to make the question as clear as possible and refine it to help who wanna answering me

Answer (score 2):

### GUI

Depending on which Ubuntu version you have,

- #### Before 13.04

  In Nautilus, go to this menu:

  > Edit → Preferences
- #### 13.04 and later

  In Nautilus, go to this menu:

  > Files → Preferences

#### Then,

in the 'Behaviour' tab, enable "Run executable text files with they are opened"

[image]

---

### Command line

If you prefer a command:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/executable-text-activation "'launch'"
```

---

Note: Both GUI and command line methods work only for Nautilus (the default graphical file manager in Ubuntu)

Comment: In 12.10,for nautilus it's edit->preferences->behaviour

Comment: Ok got it... But it's Edit->prefernces->behaviour

Comment: @minerz029 Ok friend i think that's it thanks

Comment: @minerz029 This answer is only relative to nautilus(that is fine for 99% cases). Can we do the same with CLI. That would be more appropriate as it won't be file manager based.

Comment: It's better now.

Comment: @adityapatil: All methods, both GUI and CLI, will be only for a specific file manager. I've added a command for completeness, however it only works for nautilus.

Comment: Thank you so much for providing the command line method!  Everyone on the internet seems to mention only the GUI way.