# Shell script not working

Tags: xampp, nautilus-script

For a suggested solution in another topic I tried to write my first shell script. It did not work as intended.

In order to get a quick access to the folder /opt/lampp/htdocs when using XAMPP I tried to create a desktop shell script:

```
gksudo nautilus /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

and saved it to a file named htdocs_open.sh and saved it on my desktop ("Skrivbord" in Swedish) under the folder /home/lars/Skrivbord

I also changed the permissions using:

```
chmod +x htdocs_open.sh
```

When I check the permissions it now looks like this:

```
-rwxrwxr-x  1 lars lars   35 jul 26 16:31 htdocs_open.sh*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 lars lars   34 jul 25 23:43 htdocs_open.sh~*
```

When I doubbleclick the icon on my desktop it just open up the script in gedit.

Why do I get a double set of files with one having "~" in the end?
Why is my shell script not running as a shell script?

Comment: @kenn  I was just looking for this link...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to edit your script to look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
gksudo nautilus /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

the tilde at the end of the filename `~` indicates that the file is a backup

Comment: I updated the script as you suggested but it still just open up the script in gedit.

Comment: Thanks, this hint in combination with a previous post, http://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus, helped me.