# After upgrade interface is gone and terminal won't activate

Tags: unity, 14.04, 13.10, upgrade

- I can run terminal commands by using a text file on the desktop but I can't run the terminal using a keyboard shortcut.  (Make sure you are able to [run as an executable](https://askubuntu.com/a/521111/109593))
- All windows open on top of each other in the top left, have no menu bar and can't be moved. I don't think I can change focus between windows.
  Running the command `unity` flashes up the UI but it then immediately crashes(?)
- Going into `ccsm` and disabling some bits didn't change anything.

See the image below - I can just see my desktop and the background. I can click with the cursor.
[image]

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu do you use? I may help you by downgrading Unity but i'll need to find your exact version. Why have you mentioned 2 tags (14.04 and 13.10) for your question.

Comment: Make sure Ubuntu desktop and unity are installed: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop unity`

Comment: I am upgrading fromn 13.10 to 14.04. Disabling unity in ccsm, using the specified reinstall and then reactivating and running unity fixed it, thanks :)

Comment: @cassiopeia guess I was too late. I'll still post it as an answer for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall ubuntu-desktop and unity from a virtual console.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop unity
```

That should fix it. Sometimes corrupt packages come through so you should reinstall them.