# Install projectlibre in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I am trying to install project [ProjectLibre](http://www.projectlibre.org/) in a new installation of Ubuntu 14.04. I am new at this and need step by step help. Thanks.

Comment: The right download link is http://sourceforge.net/projects/projectlibre/files/ProjectLibre/1.5.9/ -there you will find the .deb

Comment: You also might want to look into planner (available in software centre, cross platform I believe)

Answer (score 13):

Let's have a look at that for you. As far as I can tell, there is no PPA or automated way to do this. Should someone see a way that I'm missing, please edit this answer and fix it. That said, this means that you will have to install it manually.

1) To start, open your software updater and verify that you're up to date.

2)Then go to `http://sourceforge.net/projects/projectlibre/files/ProjectLibre/` and select the newest version(1.5.9 when this post was written), then download the file that ends in .deb.

3) Now, open your file manager and navigate to your Downloads folder. You should see the .deb file right there, named something like `projectlibre_1.5.9-1.deb`. Double click on it.

4) The Software Center will open and remind you that you had better trust this software. Click the install button on the right.

5) This should pull in the dependencies, or at least inform you as to what those are during the install.

6) Now your new software is installed and ready for use.

Comment: Downloaded it but it came as a rpm file and Software center does not open. Instead I get Archive Manager.

Comment: You have to download the .deb file for it to run

Comment: make sure yougo to the link which was provided in his post.not google.In that link you find the folder for the latest version and there is a .deb file.

Comment: I install "projectlibre_1.6.2-1.deb" on ubuntu 14.04 and get this message: "The package is of bad quality - The installation of a package which violates the quality standards isn't allowed. This could cause serious problems on your computer. Please contact the person or organisation who provided this package file and include the details beneath"

Comment: As for now (02-2019) I found neither a PPA. Please let it know, when a PPA for ProjectLibre appears. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

By default the Linux download is an RPM, which is a type of file to package software different from what is used by Ubuntu, as Ubuntu uses .deb files - or Debian packages. You can either convert the RPM to a Debian package, or go into the download section of the ProjectLibre site and download the Debian package directly, if available.

First try to download the Debian package directly and install it:

- Go to the [download section](http://sourceforge.net/projects/projectlibre/files/ProjectLibre/) of the ProjectLibre site and click on the directory with the latest version.
- See if there's a .deb file.
- If there is, click on it to download. The currently latest version is 1.6.1 and for this version, this is the Debian package file: [projectlibre_1.6.1-1.deb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/projectlibre/files/ProjectLibre/1.6.1/projectlibre_1.6.1-1.deb/download). After downloading, just click on it to install.

If you cannot find a Debian package for the version you want to install:

- Just hit the download button on the [ProjectLibre site](http://www.projectlibre.org/). This downloads the RPM file for the latest version.
- Now install `alien` to convert the RPM and install as shown on the [ProjectLibre blog](http://www.projectlibre.org/blog/version-159-missing-ubuntumintdebian-download) (Thank You [mytrant](http://www.projectlibre.org/users/mytrant)):

  ```
  sudo apt-get install alien
  sudo alien -ic package_file.rpm
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Seems the .deb package is of poor quality, wrong usernames for example.

I would recommend getting the pre-build tar.gz and unpacking that.

1. Fetch the latest tar.gz [projectlibre-1.6.2.tar.gz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/projectlibre/files/ProjectLibre/1.6.2/projectlibre-1.6.2.tar.gz/download) - This might be outdated  so check sourceforge for newer versions if needed
2. Open with file-roller and unpack to desired install directory. Personally I pick /opt but you need root privileges for that.
3. Start the projectlibre.sh script, either from terminal or follow this question. [How do I run executable scripts from nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus)

Comment: It seems to me this answer is missing a few steps. I had to first build the project by running `ant` in the `openproj/build/` directory. This outputs the necessary jar files into the `openproj/build/dist/` directory. Then the `projectlibre.sh` script was still unable to find the jar files. So I made a symbolic link from the script to the location of the jar files. E.g.  `cd openproj/build/dist/ && ln -s ../resources/projectlibre.sh`. Then when I executed from that directory everything worked.