# How to run a tcl program/script

Tags: scripts

I have a small tcl script which I am trying to run. I have changed the permissions to allow execution of the script (although it did require sudo access to do so?)
checking the Ubuntu Software Centre, tcl is loaded.
So how do I run it? Does it have to be run from command line?
Shouldn't I be able to run it by double clicking on the script name?

Comment: Or: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus (and a few more)

Answer (score 2):

To run a TCL script from the command line, cd to the appropriate directory and then `tclsh your_script.tcl`

The effects of double clicking it depend upon the configuration of your desktop, and also what the script actually does - it may only send any output to the console, for which you'd need to have run it from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies with you not configuring the Nautilus properly.

Refer to this post [How do I run executable scripts in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus) , change the Executable Text Files to `Run executable text files when they are opened`.

You can try the following helloworld script to test, the first line please change it to the path of your tclsh (you can find that by `which tclsh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
package require Tk
button .b -text {Push Me} -command {tk_messageBox -message {hello, world}}
pack .b
```

[image]

The result will look something like this.