# Ubuntu Server 14.04 - won't run bash script file from desktop

Tags: server, bash, nautilus, scripts

I know there are tons of this question on here already but none of them seem to have solved my issue.

I've done a clean install of 14.04 Server and install Unity (I know, boss asked for it so he can do some things himself) with this;

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

He uses file.sh to execute a special program which works flawlessly from command line but it won't run from the GUI. Boss wants GUI so I need to figure this out.

I've set it executable from the properties window, set it executable from CLI with chmod +x, run

```
gconftool-2 --set /schemas/apps/nautilus/preferences/execute_text_activation --type=string ask
```

Tried creating a script.desktop file but get a generic execution error I haven't been able to resolve yet.

I don't have to use Unity so if XFCE or Gnome resolves the problem I'll do it. If anyone has any more ideas I would very grateful to hear them!

Comment: Hi Florian, I tried everything listed there and the script still does not execute.

Comment: What happens if you try to run the script? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: I get the spinning wheel and nothing. I just tried with a test script that does nothing but echo "test" >> ./test.log and it doesn't seem to actually execute the script.

Comment: *UPDATE* So apparently setting the nautilus preferences in gconf isn't the same as hitting the radio button in the GUI, just tried on Ubuntu Desktop. However I can't get to the GUI on Server because there isn't any File, Edit, View menus. Anyone have an idea how to get those back? or set that option via CLI?

Comment: gconf isn't used any more but got replaced by dconf/gsettings. See the question linked above for how to use them.

Comment: Use the full path to the script in the launcher. If that fails, review the code. Their may be something wrong with your script. With the large number of successful users at http://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus I'm certain it's something simple that you missed rather than a problem with the answers given. (which ones did you try and how did they fail?)

Comment: AH! I missed the one reply for gsettings, none of the graphic options worked. Thanks again for your help and sorry for the duplicate.