# creating an executable file

Tags: executable, execute-command

I want to create a file which will execute a code, for example:

```
sleep 60s; dbus-send --print-reply --system --dest=org.freedesktop.UPower /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend
```

-so that double-clicking on it will be equal to open the terminal and write it in there.

How do I do it?
(In windows, I think, it is a `.bat` file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run executable scripts in Nautilus?](http://askubuntu.com/q/286621/338915)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Linux, we use bash (`.sh`) scripts.

To make a a bash script execute on double click you need to make it executable, and add the line `#!/bin/bash` to the start.

The file should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 60s; dbus-send --print-reply --system --dest=org.freedesktop.UPower /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend
```

Make it executable with:

```
chmod +x nameofscript.sh
```

You'll also want to follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/286651/146980) guide.