# Create double click executable file

Tags: command-line, scripts, 16.04, files, executable

I would like to create a file, which could be saved in the Desktop or in another folder, which upon a user double click on it executes some commands, one of which should be as super user (sudo) and which executes another file.

An example of the commands I would like to execute could be this one:

```
cd Desktop/TargetFolder
sudo ./FileToExecute
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial

Comment: install gksu and just make a shortcut to the script on your desktop then add gksu before the command. ... `gksu /home/user/Desktop/TargetFolder/FileToExecute`

Answer (score 0):

Creating an .sh (same as .exe in `Windows`) file would do. You can make it executable by this command:
`chmod +x nameofscript.sh`

You may have a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus/286651#286651) one as well which elaborates a bit more.