# Unable to run a script from a text file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a simple script that I want to be able to run by double clicking a text file and having it run in terminal so i don't have to do it manually

```
#!bin/bash
$ cd /home/tyler/df_linux
$ ./df
```

I've tried "allow executing file as program" but the file still opens in gedit.

I've also used `sudo chmod +x df` while in the directory, terminal asks for my password, i enter it, and then nothing happens.

I've been looking around the internet and my problems are similar to that of if my HDD was NTFS format, i checked using `sudo blkid -o list > ~/myFileSytems` and I can see that the script I'm trying to run is in an ext4 partition; so, that isn't the issue.

I've been looking around the internet all day and have found people with similar problems but none of the solutions that I have found have worked.

My question was marked as a duplicate of [How do I run executable scripts in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus) and i do not understand why, my problem has nothing to do with nautilus and i cannot seem to find any program called nautilus on my computer.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.03 and I am trying to run my script in terminal, I am using hashbang and the color of the text in my script has changed to identify that linux understands that it is a script, but the script will not run when I double click the file.

Comment: Have you checked if you have a shebang?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run executable scripts in Nautilus?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus)

Comment: @FlorianDiesch i saw that question and none of the anwsers in it worked for me.

edwinksl sorry for my ignorance but i am unaware of what a shebang is, im still rather new to linux

Comment: @Tyler Can you perhaps add to your question what your script contains if it isn't excessively long?

Comment: @edwinksl the OP already contains the script, essentially what it does is run another script thats in an inconvenient location that launches the program.  the second script is as fallows:
#!/bin/sh
DF_DIR=$(dirname "$0")
cd "${DF_DIR}"
export SDL_DISABLE_LOCK_KEYS=1 # Work around for bug in Debian/Ubuntu SDL patch.
#export SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED=1 # Centre the screen.  Messes up resizing.
./libs/Dwarf_Fortress "$@" # Go, go, go! :)
---------
this script came with and launches the game "dwarf fortress"found here:http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/
that script wont run on double click either

Comment: @Tyler  when you post code in the comments it is hard to read , because it's all jammed up. Use paste.ubuntu.com , post the contents, then provide link here. One thing that I've noticed is that you are calling   `./libs/Dwarf_Fortress "$@" ` This is calling `Dwarf_Fortress` with command line parameters  given to the script. In your example posted above, you only call `./df` and no arguments ; what is expected is something like `./df one_arg second_arg`  . I'd like to help you troubleshoot the stuff , so let me know once you post it to the pastebin site or find me in the askubuntu chat

Comment: @FlorianDiesch This question is not a duplicate. OP clearly knows how to run scripts and he even allowed it in the Nautilus. Please retract your close vote, as the issue here is different . Potentially there is a syntax error of sorts

Comment: ***CLOSE VOTERS** Please retract the votes, as the issue here is very different from the suggested duplicate. OP clearly knows how to run scripts and allow them in file manager.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/18854654/
this script (script #1 as it runs first) was created by me. the first line tells terminal to look in the correct directory, the second line causes script #2 to run.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/18854513/  script #2 (as it runs second) this script was not created by me and was included with dwarf fortress, the script does its job and launches the intended program.

when i run the commands in script #1 in terminal manually it works properly and runs script #2, which then launches my game. therefore i know the code works. the issue is -> next comment

Comment: script #1 to run when i double click on the icon for it on the desktop

i have to step away from the computer for the night unfortunatly

Comment: What you've posted doesn't appear to be a valid script (1) `#!bin/bash` isn't a valid interpreter (it needs to be `#!/bin/bash` - note the leading slash) and (2) you appear to have included shell prompts `$` at the start of each command. Until you can execute it in a terminal using `./scriptname` it is pointless trying to get it to run as a double-click executable.

Comment: @steeldriver ive edited the script and i can get it to run via ./scriptname so now we know for sure that the script works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Thunar (XFCE): https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=194464

Using Dolphin (KDE): http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1882254

Please post what file manager you are using.

**EDIT:** Script #1's lines appear to have `$`s before them. Remove those.

Comment: I tried both and the instructions for dolphin worked! I'm now able to launch my program by double clicking on the script.