# Stremio.sh not launching stremio

Tags: scripts

I use Stremio to watch films and series online.
The Stremio package comes with many files, and two of them can be used to launch the program; Stremio-runtime (I don't use it because this laucher makes stremio freeze) and Stremio.sh, which I do use.

My Stremio folder is in my home directory, and to launch it I have to use terminal:

```
cd Stremio/
./Stremio.sh
```

Because even with "run the file as a program", when I double click Stremio.sh, it opens with gedit?

What is wrong?

Comment: Try `sh ~/Stremio/Stremio.sh`

Comment: I can run it trough terminal! I want to run it with double click.

Comment: If not possible, how do I remove terminal after launching?

Comment: If you want to run it from terminal, and be able to close it, run the sh and press Ctrl+Z, or run `nohup sh ~/Stremio/stremio.sh`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run executable scripts in Nautilus?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to open executables with double-click:

1. Open Nautilus
2. Open the menu *Edit > Preferences > Behavior > **Executable text files***
3. Choose either:

   - *Run executable text files when they are opened*
   - *Ask each time*