# Execute sh file with java command

Tags: command-line, 18.04, java

#### Translated

I'm looking for a similar solution to creating a `bat` file in Windows on Ubuntu 18.04, I have a `java` file in which I make the call via console with the command `java -jar routine.jar` however I would do the same routine to streamline with an executable like in `bat` files.

I made a file called `backup.sh` with the same internal command and I applied `chmod+x` and made the change via Nautilus giving the execution permission via software, still it is not executed via terminal, can you help me?

#### Original

Estou buscando uma solução semelhante a criação de um arquivo `bat` no Windows no Ubuntu 18.04, eu tenho um arquivo `java` no qual eu faço a chamada via console com o comando `java -jar rotina.jar` no entanto, gostaria de fazer a mesma rotina para agilizar com um executável como em arquivos `bat`.

Fiz um arquivo chamado `backup.sh` com o mesmo comando interno e apliquei o `chmod+x` e fiz a alteração via Nautilus dando a permissão de execução via software, ainda assim o mesmo não é executado via terminal, podem me auxiliar?

Comment: English, please!

Answer (score 0):

- Make a text file
- Name it `backup.sh`
- Put in the file,

  ```
  #!/bin/bash 
  java -jar $HOME/path/to/file.jar
  ```
- save the file
- change permissions so it’s executable

  ```
  chmod u+x ./backup.sh
  ```

To execute via the terminal, use

```
./backup.sh
```

Comment: but is there a way to make as a bat file on Windows? When I perform a double-click it'll start running? doing like this is almost the same performing the command on terminal

Comment: @RinarikatoMekitoji try the answers here, https://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus

Comment: I've tried with dconf-editor and neither worked, the 18.04 is being a pain to me, any ideas? it continues to open in gedit