# .sh file does not run on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, scripts

I have upgraded from lubuntu 16.04 to ubuntu 18.04 (German version).
A shell script which used to run will not start any more.
I have checked the box "run as executable" in the properties, but neither left- nor rightclick offers running the script. It only will be opened in leafpad.
I have also tried `chmod +x`, no success.

As far as I  know the necessary java packages are included in ubuntu 18.04.
What else can I try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus

Comment: As far as I know, Gnome 3 doesn't run the scripts when opened from the file manager.

Comment: Also, please note that `chmod -x` removes the execution permission from a file. To make a file executable you must run `chmod +x`

Comment: How do you know it doesn’t run? Please [edit] and add the full script using the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

make it executable with:

```
chmod +x your_file.sh
```

if you use "-x" in chmod command, like you wrote in your question, you remove che "execute" attribute.

If you want check the attributes with:

```
ls -la /your_path/your_file.sh
```

if the file is executable you must see the "x" attibutes, like the followind:

```
-rwx------ 1 my-user my-group     114 ago 31 15:54 my_script.sh
```

Comment: .. that was a type mistake - used +x, no success.
Attributes are 
-rwxrwxr-x  1 markus markus     611 Jul 13 12:04 jameica.sh

Answer (score 0):

As I found out now (following Hello's hint), this is a nautilus problem. I installed pcman fm instrad - and everything works.