# Instead of launching program, the executable is forced to open in a text editor

Tags: executable, text, editor

Answer attempt: [How do I run executable scripts in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus)

Notice the first 2 steps in the answer:

1. Open Nautilus (folder/file explorer).
2. Open this from the menu bar: *Edit → Preferences*

I couldn't find a menu-bar in Nautilus. Where would the *Edit* option be? It wasn't found in either Nautilus or the text editor.

Comment: Please don't use instructions for a 2013 release on a modern install (ie. 18.04). Nautilus is a complete different piece of software where security is leading. Read this and see if it applies to your situation: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/05/nautilus-remove-ability-launch-binaries-apps

Comment: Rinzwind.. Thanks so much for your help, I'm extremely pleased with the results per your directions.