# How to launch a python script from .desktop launcher in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: nautilus, launcher, 19.04, tkinter

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 19.04 ,previously I had 18.04.

In 18.04 the .desktop file worked normal, I was able to launch a tkinter app from my desktop but now I am not able to launch from desktop in 19.04
This is  the file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name = UrlSaver
Version = 1.0
Exec = python /home/raviteja/link/url_app.py
Icon = /home/raviteja/link/app_icon.png
Path = /home/raviteja/link/
Terminal = False
Type = Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

This same file worked in Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: should work... maybe the command line need some adjustment. - What gives `whereis python`

Comment: python: /usr/bin/python3.7m-config /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python3.7-config /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.7m /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/lib/python3.7 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3.6 /etc/python3.7 /etc/python /etc/python2.7 /etc/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python3.7 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.6 /usr/include/python3.7 /usr/include/python3.7m /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/share/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz

Comment: try to give full path of binary `/usr/bin/python` on the `Exec` line of the desktop file

Comment: When I use thunar as file manager I am able to open it, but when I changed the path it simply diasppeared from desktop

Comment: file should be executable

Answer (score -1):

Double clicking is not allowed anymore,read : https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/05/nautilus-remove-ability-launch-binaries-apps
See : [How do I run executable scripts in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus)
for partial workaround. The dozens of .desktop files i created are still NOT launch-able.....

Comment: This is only for Nautilus.  Desktop files are something else, enabling to put an icon on yout desktop.

Comment: .desktop files were probably meant to work from the desktop folder only but they also worked from any project folder in your home-dir. That was a great way to gather some interesting webpages and open them in new chrome window all at once.  Putting them all on the desktop itself will become messy.... Nemo or other you mean i guess