# How do I make the Battery notification more obvious?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, battery, notification

Can the low battery notification's look and feel be made clearer? The default notification is very small. So sometimes, we do not even notice that notification and the laptop shuts down.

So, how can I change the look and feel for *only* the low battery notifications?

Comment: Perhaps a beeping when percentage drops below 10 that grows more annoying as it approaches 3%?

Comment: Actually, I am working in office so most of the time laptop sound is disabled. So in that scenario...

And thank for nice title. @dk-bose

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure how easy it is to tinker *only* the low battery alert notification, but you can manually set up a slightly better notification system for yourself following this hacky workaround:

1. First you'll need to install `acpi` by running

   ```
   sudo apt install acpi
   ```
2. Next you need to create a bash script. Create an empty text file, say `battery-alert.sh` and add the following lines

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   while true
       do
           export DISPLAY=:0.0
           battery_level=`acpi -b | grep -P -o '[0-9]+(?=%)'`
           if on_ac_power; then                           #check if AC is plugged in
                   :
           else
                if [ $battery_level -le 5 ]; then         #check if the battery level is below 5%, change the number after "-le" to set your preferred battery level
                   notify-send -u critical "Low Battery!" "Please plug your AC adapter, battery level: ${battery_level}%" -i battery-caution
                fi
           fi
   sleep 300                                              #wait for 300 seconds before checking again, change the number after "sleep" to set your preferred waiting period
   done
   ```
3. Save the file.
4. [Make the script executable](https://askubuntu.com/q/286621/480481) and run it. You'll get a *persistent* notification (you'll have to click it to dismiss it) if the battery level is below 5%.

You may also consider [adding the script to your startup applications](https://askubuntu.com/q/48321/480481) so that it starts automatically every time you boot your laptop.