# Why is GNOME Terminal not showing in list of applications when I try to open a file on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

GNOME Terminal not showing in list of applications to open a file with. I'd like to be able to call it from another app to execute a batch (`.sh` type) file.
OS - Ubuntu 18.04.

List of Applications:
[image: List of Applications]

The GNOME Terminal is definitely installed and runs on my system when I launch it from Favourites etc.

There are two other issues that may be related.  I also noticed in the list of applications presented a duplication e.g of File Manager etc. In addition I have a crash report log related to the GNOME desktop. I submitted the report but don't know what else to do with it.

Comment: @pomsky I'd like to be able to call it from another app to execute a batch (.sh type) file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question, I believe an '*open with Terminal*' option (to execute a script) is not there by default, but you can certainly create one. To do this follow the steps below.

1. Create an empty text file in your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory.
2. Open it with a text editor.
3. Add the following lines to it.

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Open with Terminal
   Comment=Run the script in a Terminal window
   Exec=/bin/bash -c '%U; exec bash'
   Type=Application
   Terminal=true
   Icon=utilities-terminal
   NoDisplay=true
   ```
4. Save the text file (or rename it) with a `.desktop` suffix, say as `open-with-terminal.desktop`.

Now you should find an entry called '*Open with Terminal*' in the '*Open with Other Application*' dialog.

But this might be an overkill for your *actual* goal.  If you just want to execute a script from your file manager, then see this: [How do I run executable scripts in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/q/286621/480481)

Comment: Thank you very much @pomsky ! It worked like a charm :) . I had created .desktop files for GNOME Terminal. I just didn't know that these need to be placed in the ~/.local/share/applications. Thanks for the link to running scripts in Nautilus.  I had looked into FireSSH ( no longer available) and shellinabox. I didn't have much luck with shellinabox. Running another web server to monitor a local web server is definitely an overkill. I managed to learn to log in with SSH in the process though :)  Thank you once again  for your outstanding help.