# I have an exectuable that only opens with text editor from Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, 20.04

When I use the command prompt and type ./myprogram it executes just fine, but when I try to click on the executable in nautilus it just opens the text editor. I turned on the executing permissions in the properties window but still no good. Any idea's what my issue is.

Running Ubuntu 20.04 recently upgraded

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run executable scripts in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus)

Answer (score 1):

You can set that in 'preference menu':

Behaviour -> Executable text files -> Run them

Comment: OK did that, excuse ignorance please. Still doesn't run from nautilus though. Could it have something to do with the executable ending in .desktop?

Comment: The extension does not affect a script execution in Linux. Your script might execute but not alert you that it did.