# Execute a bash file by double clicking

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Instead of following the steps at https://www.xp-pen.com/faq-56-210.html, I want to be able to double click the bash file and run the software.

I followed the steps in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=daadsaHhXB8. Still not successful. I was able to run it via cmd using `./script.sh`. But I want to be able to double click and run.

I would really appreciate if anyone can help me with this. My OS is Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not very familiar with 20.04, but [these directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044798/how-do-i-run-a-script-on-linux-just-by-double-clicking-it) should still work.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run executable scripts in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus)

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on the file manager used so your best be is to search for a way to achieve that through your file manager settings rather than at OS level .

Let us know which file manger you're using, then I can add more information to directly answer your questions.

Comment: How do I check the file manager?

Comment: The file manager is what you use to browse for / access files. You should be able to find that out from Help>About menu .

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

- Hit `Alt+F2`, type `dconf-editor` and hit ``Enter.
- In dconfg-editor goto: `org ➤ gnome ➤ nautilus ➤ preferences`
- Click on `executable-text-activation` and from drop down menu select:

launch: to launch scripts as programs.

OR

ask: to ask what to do via a dialog.

Close `dconf-editor` Thats it!

**Source** : **exact copy** of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42047558/13198229) answer from stack overflow.

Comment: I can now execute but its asking for root permission to run this driver. How should I handle that?

Comment: There should be an authentication for running scripts, and I don't think there is a solution for that. If you find it, feel free to post it here