# Ubuntu 21.10 Nautilus Preference menu not complete

Tags: command-line, gnome, nautilus

My nautilus HAS a preference button but it **does not show all the possible options**. For example, I was trying to set `executable-text-activation` to `launch` but I can NOT find the option in my preference as is shown here... [image: attached figure] Do you know what is a possible reason behind this?

Remark: I have tried the command line `dconf write /org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/executable-text-activation "'launch'"` to solve the example problem but it was not working.

(Solved) This is probably a duplicate of [Can't run shell script by double click in Files (Ubuntu 21.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1373507/cant-run-shell-script-by-double-click-in-files-ubuntu-21-10).

(Update) Nemo keeps more preferences compared to Nautilus.

Comment: I do not even see an option `/org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/executable-text-activation` in dconf-editor for files 40.2 in Ubuntu 21.10. Sure it is in 21.10 you see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any option comes at a cost. It was the decision not to expose this option anymore. A main reason is that launching a random file by double clicking is not anymore considered good practice, in the context of security. Something that is executable should be properly installed on a system and opened from the dedicated menu system. Developers are the only people that need to test-run scripts and executables that are not installed. However, they will not use a file manager for that.

Comment: Why did you remove the option to get thumbnails for images >10 MB?