# Is dconf-tools/editor not included in ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Unity)?

Tags: 14.04, unity

I was reading an answer I required to a ['question'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138908/how-to-execute-a-script-just-by-double-clicking-like-exe-files-in-windows) when I saw that dconf-tools/editor is missing from my fresh Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Unity) installation.

- Has it been removed from the default programs installed? (If Y ? Why : )
- Or is my fresh installation broken?
- Or has Ubuntu added an alternative to dconf-tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dconf-editor` package is available to be installed in Ubuntu 14.04, but it is not a part of the default installed packages. It was never a part of the default install.