# How to make an executable text file run a .jar file with arguments

Tags: command-line, bash, java, jar

I need to make a simple executable text file (preferably via chmod +x, but that isn't necessary) that runs a .jar file and passes in JVM arguments as well as jar-specific args. It must also run in terminal sp I can see the ouput.

```
#!/bin/bash
java -Xmx4G -Xms2G file.jar nogui
```

where nogui is the program-specific argument, doesn't seem to do anything when run in terminal (it doesn't even open a terminal window).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute a script just by double clicking like .EXE files in Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/138908/how-to-execute-a-script-just-by-double-clicking-like-exe-files-in-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a JAR file via `java` you need the switch `-jar`.

```
#!/bin/bash
java -Xmx4G -Xms2G -jar file.jar nogui
```

Comment: wow, I can't believe I missed that. I knew I needed it, just one of those oops moments. thanks