# How to launch shell scripts from XFCE desktop?

Tags: xfce, thunar

They will only open in a text editor. "Open With" doesn't offer an option to execute. The shell scripts are +x so they should run normally.

As a workaround, I set them to be opened with the terminal emulator, but it is not ideal.

Comment: It's different question since it's about XFCE and the answers are all about Gnome and nautilus.

Comment: The answer about Thunar is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138908/how-to-execute-a-script-just-by-double-clicking-like-exe-files-in-windows/871986#871986).

Comment: @Marco- Also, [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1170255/925128) on how to achieve the purpose with custom actions in Thunar (without re-enabling that "risky" feature).

Comment: You can make `.sh` files execute on double click without a terminal window by _right click on a file -> Open With Other Application -> Use custom command -> type "bash" in the input field_ then tick "Use as default for this kind of file", and press "Open"

Answer (score -1):

Even when marked as executable, the system doesn't know what to use to interpret the script. If it is a POSIX shell script, add this line to the very beginning of your script:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Should it require bash or some other shell, use e.g. for bash

```
#!/bin/bash
```

The same applies to other executable text files, such as python programs:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: I have that line in the script and Thunar open the file in text editor.

Comment: Did you make your script executable? I.e. `chmod +x <filename>`?

Comment: Yes, I've found the solution and added answer to the duplicate question [exec by clicking in Xfce](http://askubuntu.com/questions/138908/how-to-execute-a-script-just-by-double-clicking-like-exe-files-in-windows#answer-871986)