# Open Android Studio "studio.sh" by double click on script file in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, android-studio

I used Ubuntu 14.04, As I have to open `Terminal` and Drag-n-Drop `studio.sh` to open Android Studio every time.

Is there any other simple way to open it.

I thought to create script file and by clicking on that file open Android Studio Automatically.

Any Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run Android Studio by double clicking on its icon, you will need to create a .desktop file for it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Android Studio
Comment=Android Studio script
Exec=/home/user/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
Icon=/home/user/android-studio/bin/studio.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Save the above as a file on your Desktop with a `.desktop` extension.

For first time it will give warning to trust on android studio.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Nice Answer, I have change permission as executable file after creating it.

Comment: I have one problem now that icon is not showing me on desktop but when I open desktop as folder, its displaying.

Answer (score 1):

I found best solution as I think:

Android Studio gives the functionality to create **Command Line Launcher** and **Desktop Entry**:

## To Create Command Line Launcher:

- Go To **Tools** menu -> Select **Create Command Line Launcher** -> Enter your **Password**
- It will create one launcher file on this location: `/home/.AndroidStudio1.5/system/tmp`
- Simply it will also run like drag-n-drop on terminal.

## To Create Desktop Launcher:

- Click on `Create Desktop Entry..` from **Tools** menu.

[image]

- It will be prompt for password, enter password of your current login.
- Finally it will be display notification in Android Studio screen like:

[image]

- You can see in **Applications => Programming => Android Studio**, and you may see on desktop also after restarting system.

Thank you. :)