# Executing script in GUI

Tags: execute-command

I have an executable file in my home directory (`/home/user/filename/filename.sh`). I am a non-root user. How do I make this script launch by typing the name in terminal? Not using the `cd` command, `chmod` command, and `./`. I also want to launch the script by clicking just the application icon.

Comment: We are here to help. So, no need to put that in title. Edit your question with a better title please.

Comment: To make it double clickable u first have to to use chmod! And everytime time chmod when u put object file on different machines

Comment: And http://askubuntu.com/q/138908/158442

Answer (score 0):

```
cat <script here> | /bin/bash.
```

This will print the contents of the script and pipe it to /bin/bash.
Note that if you use this method, the shebang (#!/path/to/shell) will not work. Replace /bin/bash with the shell of your choice.

If you want to launch the application from the GUI, make a .desktop file for it.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=<Name>
Exec=<command>
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
```

Place the .desktop file in the same directory as your script.

By the way, chmod works if you are the owner of the script (and chmod is executable).