# Zenity script: dismiss window with close (x) button or Esc

Tags: scripts, zenity

Following [this solution](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/4271/170) I have a zenity script to [ask me what to do when clicking an executable script](https://askubuntu.com/a/876581/47206) in Thunar or [a desktop file](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10955/170) in Pantheon Files:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

zenity --question --text="What to do?" \
       --ok-label=Run \
       --cancel-label=Edit

case $? in
    0)thunar "$1"
    ;;
    1)gedit $1
    ;;
esac
```

And it shows this:

[image]

But there is a small glitch: you cannot dismiss the dialog at this point: using close window button, <kbd>Esc</kbd> or  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> equates to the `--cancel-label` option in the script and will open the file in text editor.

How could I edit the script so that when  <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed the zenity windows would close without farther action?

---

#### Edit after comment:

I have got this in a comment:

> either let the --question dialog --timeout to get a third return value (5)

Indeed, `--timeout=4` will close the dialog after that number of secs.

> or you can go for multiple choice dialog by --list --radiolist

What does that mean?

Comment: I had an answer typed out for you over at U&L and then you deleted your question... very funny. Anyhow, you can either let the `--question` dialog `--timeout` to get a third return value (5) or you can go for multiple choice dialog by `--list --radiolist`. Have fun.

Comment: @frostschutz - Leaving back  what's gone:  I would very much appreciate you posting an answer here with all the details. Giving examples  would not only help me with what I ask here, but  would give me some clues for other uses of `zenity`  :) - what I know now about it is pretty much the script above. `let the --question dialog --timeout to get a third return value (5)` it's something that needs an interpretation for me.

Comment: Could easily make a small Gtk window with any keybinding you want. :)

Answer (score 1):

A simplified script that uses `yad` can be a workaround in order to have the window dismissed as intended; labels are 'OK' for run and 'Cancel'
for edit.

`sudo apt install yad`

And the script is:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

yad --text="Execute the file? (press 'Cancel' to edit)" 

case $? in
    0)thunar "$1"
    ;;
    1)gedit $1
    ;;
esac
```

[image]

---

A version of the initial script (somewhat improved based on the comment), which even in absence of action will close the window after a number of seconds:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

zenity --question --text="Press RUN to execute -- Press EDIT, ESC or close (x) to open as text -- or WAIT 7 seconds to dismiss" \
       --ok-label=RUN \
       --cancel-label=EDIT \
       --timeout=7

case $? in
    0)thunar $1
    ;;
    1)gedit $1
    ;;
esac
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Simple example of a radiolist

There is a simple example of a radiolist in this link,

http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/265/a-complete-zenity-dialog-examples-2/

### Example with --list

I think it is easier to use a simple list (with the option `--list` but without `--radiolist`)

```
$ ans=$(zenity  --list  --title "What to do?"  --column "What to do?" Run Edit 2> /dev/null); echo "ans=$ans"
ans=Run
$ ans=$(zenity  --list  --title "What to do?"  --column "What to do?" Run Edit 2> /dev/null); echo "ans=$ans"
ans=Edit
$ ans=$(zenity  --list  --title "What to do?"  --column "What to do?" Run Edit 2> /dev/null); echo "ans=$ans"
ans=
```

[image]