# It is possible to add password show in zenity linux

Tags: lubuntu, button, zenity

It is possible to make zenity dialog with password show button or something like this ?[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not implemented in Zenity.

Comment: Maybe it is in other linux dialog creation tool ?

Comment: Not sure why my answer was downvoted. Zenity has a --pasword option, but there is no implementation of what OP asks, i.e., have a checkbox to show the password.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extra button with <kbd>Show Password</kbd> and when user clicks mount a duplicate form except the password field is defined as not hidden.

You can do this with `yad` for sure but I couldn't find a reference for `zenity`:

- [Bash template to use zenity (or yad) to insert / edit / delete records in a file or database](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894888/bash-template-to-use-zenity-or-yad-to-insert-edit-delete-records-in-a-file)