# How to launch only shell scripts from Nautilus

Tags: scripts, nautilus, executable, mime-type

This is related to questions like [“How do I run executable scripts in Nautilus?”](https://askubuntu.com/q/286621) or [“How to execute a script just by double clicking like .EXE files in Windows?”](https://askubuntu.com/q/138908).

I would also like to have shell scripts run if they are opened in the file manager (Nautilus), but the usual setting (`org ➤ gnome ➤ nautilus ➤ preferences ➤ executable-text-activation`) is not fine-grained enough for my purposes. If I set it to `ask` or `launch`, *any text file* with the executable bit set will (ask to) be launched as a script. This is problematic because we have some scripts on a file system (CIFS) which does not support Unix permissions (owner/group, rwx). That means that when I mount this file system, I can only either

1. set *all* files as executable (including, of course, any text files) or
2. set all files as *not* executable.

Consequently, when I open any text file (`*.txt`/MIME type `text/plain`), even if it has no script-related contents, the file will still (ask to) be executed. This is really annoying and irritating for inexperienced users – of course I don’t want to “run” a `text/plain` file.

Is there a way to make Nautilus treat *only actual shell scripts* (e. g. MIME type `application/x-shellscript`) as executable scripts?

Comment: You can mount the remote files system without the executable bit on regular files as you mention in the question. Or is that unacceptable for some reason?

Comment: @DavidFoerster As I said, there are both normal text files and shell scripts on the remote file system. If I mount without the executable bit set, the scripts cannot be executed at all anymore.

Comment: Fair enough. Though one can always run scripts directly through their interpreter (e. g. `bash my-script` instead of `./my-script`).

Comment: @DavidFoerster Yeah, I guess that’s true. Doesn’t help me with launching from the file manager GUI, though…