# howto create script to customize configuration of Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: 16.04, scripts, xubuntu

right now I have multiple instructions that I have to add separately by manual labor (start terminal, copy paste instructions, insert instructions into text file), so I thought there must be a way to pack all of these commands into a single text file and have it run once.

For example I need to do 2 configurations:

### 1st Configuration

1. create file with:

   ```
   sudo nano /usr/local/bin/loadFlysoftPOS
   ```
2. copy following text into the above text file:

   ```
   #/bin/bash until pids=$(pidof mysqld)
   do  
   sleep 1
   done
   cd ~/Dokumente/dist/
   java -jar POSv2.jar > log.txt
   ```
3. make it runnable by current user

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/loadFlysoftPOS
   ```

### 2nd Configuration

1. create file:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules
   ```
2. insert text into file:

   ```
   SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", DRIVERS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0525", ATTRS{idProduct}=="a700", SYMLINK+="usb/sewoo1", GROUP="lp"
   ```

So is it possible to store all those instructions into a single script and have it run once? Also importantly is to override any existing file, so if there already is a file called /etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules, its content should be cleared and overwritten by the contents provided by the new script.

Thanks guys for the enlightment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nano` is an interactive text editor - IMHO it isn't helpful for creating file content programatically.

For your first case, I'd suggest using a [here document](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Heredocs_And_Herestrings):

```
cat << \EOF > /usr/local/bin/loadFlysoftPOS
#!/bin/bash 

until $(pidof mysqld)
do  
  sleep 1
done
cd $HOME/Dokumente/dist/ && java -jar POSv2.jar > log.txt
EOF

chmod +x /usr/local/bin/loadFlysoftPOS
```

For the second case, a simple `echo` should do:

```
echo 'SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", DRIVERS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0525", ATTRS{idProduct}=="a700", SYMLINK+="usb/sewoo1", GROUP="lp"' > /etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules
```

Put the whole thing in a file with its own shebang:

File: `myscript.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

cat << \EOF > /usr/local/bin/loadFlysoftPOS
#!/bin/bash 

until $(pidof mysqld)
do  
  sleep 1
done
cd $HOME/Dokumente/dist/ && java -jar POSv2.jar > log.txt
EOF

chmod +x /usr/local/bin/loadFlysoftPOS

echo 'SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", DRIVERS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0525", ATTRS{idProduct}=="a700", SYMLINK+="usb/sewoo1", GROUP="lp"' > /etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules
```

Make *it* executable, and run it with `sudo`

```
chmod +x myscript.sh
sudo ./myscript.sh
```

Comment: thank you so much for your effort in detailing how this work. Additionaly you provided the BashGuide/InputAndOutput that provide so much useful information in this matter. You just saved my day! Thanks again for your patentience and dilligence!

Comment: I did some further research and found this (https://askubuntu.com/questions/138908/how-to-execute-a-script-just-by-double-clicking-like-exe-files-in-windows) to help me in setting up the shell script as an executable similar to run by double-click a .exe file. Hope it helps someone.