# Running a specific script with double click

Tags: bash, scripts, sh, doubleclick

I want to create a script that automatically downloads a zip from the internet like the following sh script named test.sh :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
curl -o csvs.zip https://randomCloudCsv/download
```

But I want to run it with double click and not with

```
./test.sh
```

from the terminal

I was thinking that defining this behaviour would also require another script that makes this preference specific only for this script as it would be dangerous to be a default for every random script.
My question is similar with that [How to execute a script just by double clicking like .EXE files in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138908/how-to-execute-a-script-just-by-double-clicking-like-exe-files-in-windows) but I'll keep the question here as the answer I got is more straightforward (notice that the other question is also editied and at the beggining it didn't look like mine)

Comment: Why not just create a desktop icon just like the others on your desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a .desktop file, its about-like a windows .lnk

Create the file on the desktop
`nano $(xdg-user-dir DESKTOP)/mylauncher.desktop`
And paste the following text in the desktop file

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec='/path/to/your/script.sh'
Name=Give it a Name
Comment=Why not add some comment
Icon=/path/to/an/icon/for/the/launcher.svg
```

Make the .desktop file executable
`chmod +x $(xdg-user-dir DESKTOP)/mylauncher.desktop`

You can find icons under `/usr/share/icons/`